# What does disposition mean in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The working papers document
> The auditor’s conclusions and the reasons as to why those conclusions were reached. The disposition of each audit finding identified during the audit and its related corrective action should be documented. Working papers should be completed throughout the audit.

What is the meaning of disposition of each audit finding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford's Learners dictionary gives a definition as: [the way something is placed or arranged](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disposition#:%7E:text=%2F%CB%8Cd%C9%AAsp%C9%99%CB%88z%C9%AA%CA%83n%2F-,%2F%CB%8Cd%C9%AAsp%C9%99%CB%88z%C9%AA%CA%83n%2F,people%20of%20a%20nervous%20disposition)

It could mean the nature/details of the findings.

Alternatively, Merriam Webster gives a definition as: [final arrangement : SETTLEMENT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disposition).

It could mean the decision or judgement of the findings. This is more likely as it goes on to mention corrective action.